# Tarea en segundo plano con discord.py envio de mensajes automaticamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Como hacer que cuando alguien se conecta mi bot mande un mensaje a general, no un mensaje de bienvenida si no unos mensajes que estan en dos lista y que siempre los envia aleatoria mente, por el mometo tengo esto de codigo.

```
@tasks.loop(3)
async def halago_o_insulto(ctx):
    si = True
    dom_2 = random.choice(lista and lista_2)
    await ctx.send(dom_2)
```

Siempre que alguien se conecte que envie un mensaje.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Tarea en segundo plano "cls" con discord.py](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/418251/tarea-en-segundo-plano-cls-con-discord-py)

Comment: No responde a mi pregunta porque tampoco esa pregunta tiene respuesta.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres por "cuando alguien se conecta mi bot"?